# Algorithm to adjust color brightness

Tags: graphics, colors

I am doing a project trying to simulate Google Analytic Map Overlays.  [Take a look at this link](http://linux.dsplabs.com.au/power-of-reddit-spreddit-digg-stumbleupon-delicious-awstats-detailed-web-server-seo-statistics-p57/) to see what I mean (you need to scroll down to where it says "Here is a geographical country-based visitor volume overview courtesy of Google Analytics").  The Flash mapping tool I have supports Hex Color codes (e.g. color='FFFFCC').  If I am not mistaken this is basically RGB coding?

I am looking for an algorithm where I can computationally create the color codes for a select number of shades of green.

It seems I really want HSV type calculation and not a RGB one.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way to accomplish this is to select a set of colors and then map then to different segments of your data. I suppose you may need more flexibility.

If you want to calculate color. You can use HSV internally, and then covert it to RGB using this algorithm:

http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html

Comment: Thanks - I will take a look at this.  Yes - I would need more flexibility.  In the end I would probably make the number of "Steps" be user configurable.  Essentially what I want to do is define a "Dark" color and a "Light" color.  Then be able to have a fixed number of steps between.