# How can I change contrast of an image by using javascript and html slider (not using canvas)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, contrast

As the title, I want to create a slider using html and javascript (or jQuery, CSV,...) to change contrast of an image. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754604/want-to-create-a-simple-image-brightness-control-slider) topic. However, I don't want to use Canvas in HTML5.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you working on creating a slider for controlling image contrast?

Comment: @azs06: yes. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you want something like this https://jsfiddle.net/azs06/5ah3zh3s/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS filter:

```
-webkit-filter: contrast(200%);
```

Just get the value of your HTML slider and apply the contrast filter to your image

Comment: I did your suggestion. However, when I change to contrast(0%), the color of image is gray (not completely black as docs about contrast in w3schools: 0% will make the image completely black.
Moreover, -webkit-filter did not work on IE, though I tried these prefix: -ms-, -moz-, -o-, filter. I don't know the reason why.